# Magento 2.3.4 - CMS_Block Query taking up resource

Tags: magento2.3, blocks, cms, debug

Hope someone can help because I'm aghast.

So we have a 2.3.4 store (migrated from 1.9) which we put live recently. After an hour or so, the site completely collapsed under the traffic (apparently it was only 30 or 40 people).

Since then, we've reverted the site and ran various tests on it and can't pinpoint what's bringing the store down. The server specs are more than enough to run Magento 2.

For reference, the site runs absolutely fine when there are 1 or 2 people browsing.

We've hooked the store up to a new relic and it appears the `MySQL cms_block select` query is the main offender. I assume it's this one:

```
SQL: SELECT `cbs`.`store_id` FROM `cms_block_store` AS `cbs`
 INNER JOIN `cms_block` AS `cb` ON cbs.block_id = cb.block_id WHERE (cb.block_id = :block_id)
BIND: array (
  ':block_id' => 30,
)
```

I have:

- Completely turned off all CMS blocks
- Stripped the cms/index/index of everything
- Disabled the majority of extensions
- Reverted to the default theme

Using loader.io, it seems like the site falls over when we send 30 or 40 people to the site.

I also enabled Magento SQL log and we got a 6GB file within 20 mins, haha.

I just...I have no idea where to look now. What would cause the cms_block table to take up most of the resources? Am I missing something?

The only loosely related thing I can find is [This medium article](https://yegorshytikov.medium.com/magento-2-core-performance-issue-any-magento-website-has-fix-included-6a803a3965e2), but I can't trust a guy whose judgment is clouded by how much he hates the platform. I don't want to make a database structure change based on this article alone.

It would be awfully helpful if someone could recommend what methods they'd use to debug this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved. Not the way I hoped, but the server we migrated from was using MariaDB and the new hosts were using MySQL. Switching it to MariaDB seemed to resolve the issues right away.

Hope this helps someone :)